# I don't understand how this set can be contained in $\Bbb N$

Tags: number-theory, proof-explanation, well-orders

In my lecture notes there is a proof for the division algorithm which sets $S=\{a-xb|x\in \Bbb Z, a-xb \geq 0 \}$ then says $S\subset\Bbb N$ so we can use the well ordering principle.

There's a similar proof here http://www.mathpath.org/concepts/divisionalgo.htm, although  the main body of the proof isn't relevant to my question.

My question is how can $S$ be contained in $\Bbb N$, when zero is an element of $S$ ? Surely I'm missing something here ?

Comment: $0$ is a natural number. Even if you disagree and follow the convention that $0\notin \mathbb{N}$, the set $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N}\cup \{0\}$ is well-ordered, so arguments by induction or well-ordering apply just as well to it.

Comment: $\mathbb N$ is usually taken to include $0,$ and the well-ordering principle holds in either case. If it was defined to start at one instead, perhaps your instructor made a small oversight.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I believe she must have because on the previous page she used the convention that zero is not a natural number, I see now I should just say the set is well ordered rather than saying its a subset of the naturals , so as to stay consistent with her convention :) thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some authors define the set of natural numbers starting with $0$ therefor they consider $0\in\Bbb N $

The proof of the theorem does not change whether you call $0$ a natural number or not.